# File is missing when sending form-data with boundary

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a JS script that send a file with FormData as explained [here](https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2012/01/10/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata/). I sends this request :

```
curl '...' 
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36' 
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryNXAVPG4vPIDQ65Yk' 
  --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryNXAVPG4vPIDQ65Yk\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="test"\r\n\r\ntest\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryNXAVPG4vPIDQ65Yk\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="test1"\r\n\r\ntest1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryNXAVPG4vPIDQ65Yk\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="test1"; filename="Capture du 2016-07-15 06:56:40.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryNXAVPG4vPIDQ65Yk\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Capture du 2016-07-15 06:56:40.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryNXAVPG4vPIDQ65Yk--\r\n' --compressed
```

As you can see, it sends data with WebKitFormBoundary. On the Rails part, I'm receiving : `{"test"=>"test", "test1"=>"test1"}`. The parameter `file` is missing.

Here is my JS code :

```
formData = new FormData();
formData.append('test', 'test');
formData.append('test1', 'test1');
formData.append('file', $('.file-ci')[0].files[0]);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://test.oxygene.siliga.fr/api/annexes', true)
xhr.send(formData);
```

I want to send the file in the request.

What can I do?

Comment: I just saw `form-data; name="file"; filename="Capture du ...` ? what is `file`is missing mean ?

Comment: @孙悟空 I added thee JS code. I think it have to send the file with the request.

Comment: You should set it to multipart...  wild guess

Comment: Can you please add your log (located under `log/development.log`)?

Comment: This is because I use a proxy and the request is not well transmeeted. My bad.